# Probability distribution for two-state system that depends on residence time

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, stochastic-processes, mp.mathematical-physics

I am a statistical physicist, and I've come across a problem that I don't know how to solve. I believe my issue lies with how to formulate it mathematically. I'd be very grateful for any assistance, as I've really struggled with this.

Suppose we have a system with two states, say $+$ and $-$. The waiting time distribution for switching from either state to the other is an exponential, $\psi_{\pm}(t) = \kappa_{\pm} e^{-\kappa_{\pm} t}$. So $\psi_{\pm}(t)$ is the probability distribution for the time spent in the $\mp$ state.

Let $X$ be the random variable that we are interested in. If we enter state $+$ at $t = 0$, then its probability distribution at a later time $t$ is $p_{+}(x, t)$, assuming it does not switch to $-$. Define $p_{-}(x, t)$ likewise. These distributions depend on the time spent in the state.

I would like the full probability distribution $p(x, t)$, assuming the initial state is known, say $+$. I simply don't know how to write down a general equation for $p(x, t)$...

Again, any help would be wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand what $X$ and $x$ are. Real numbers? $\pm$ states?
I also didn't understand what is $p_+$ (or $p_-$). Is it the distribution of $X$ and does $X$ depend on time $t$?

Comment: X (or x) is some random variable, it is a real number. $p_{\pm}(x, t)$ are the probability distributions of $x$ given that the system enters state $\pm$ at $t = 0$ and remains there until time $t$. 

To be more clear, $p_{\pm}(x, t = 0)$ is the probability distribution of $x$ right when the system enters state $\pm$. $p_{\pm}(x, t)$ is the probability distribution of $x$ after it waits in state $\pm$ for a time $t$. These are normalized such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p_{\pm}(x, t) = 1$.

For my particular application, I know the exact forms of $p_{\pm}(x, t)$.

Comment: Somehow, $p(x, t)$ needs to take into account switching between these states.

Comment: for example,  we are in state 2 at time 5, the process last entered state 2 at time 3.7, $X \sim p(x,1.3)$ ?  

Comment: Using my notation, we are in state $+$ at time $5$, knowing that the process entered state $+$ at time $3.7$, we have $X \sim p_{+}(x, 1.3)$. If we switch to state $−$ at time $5$ and wait there until time $7$, $X \sim p_{-}(x, 2)$. Whenever we enter either state, we start the clock again from $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first simple case: $p_+=p_-\equiv p_0$ and $\kappa_+=\kappa_-\equiv \kappa$; then all you need to know is the time $\delta t$ since the last switching event, which has an exponential distribution, hence:

$$p(x,t)=(1-e^{-\kappa t})^{-1}\int_0^t d\delta t\; \kappa e^{-\kappa \delta t}p_0(x,\delta t)$$

now the general case; you'll need to distinguish even from odd number of switching events, and find the distribution $P_{\rm even}(\delta t)$ of the time $\delta t$ since the last switching event, given that there have been an even number of switches in a time $t$, and similarly for an odd number; the a priori probability that there have been an even or odd number of switches is just given by the Poisson distribution (summing over $n$ even or $n$ odd). The integral over $P_{\rm even}(\delta t)p_{+}(x,\delta t)$ and $P_{\rm odd}(\delta t)p_{-}(x,\delta t)$ then gives the full answer.

a bit more explicit, still assuming $\kappa_+=\kappa_-\equiv \kappa$ for simplicity; it is convenient to set the first switching event at time $0$, so that the number of switching events $m=n+1$ in a time $t>0$ is $\geq 1$; the probability $P_{m,t}(\delta t)$ that there have been $m=n+1\geq 1$ switching events in a time $t$, while the last switching event was a time $\delta t\in[0,t)$ ago is given by a slight modification of the Poisson distribution,

$$ P_{m,t}(\delta t)=\frac{1}{(m-1)!}[\kappa(t-\delta t)]^{m-1}\kappa e^{-\kappa t}.$$

summing over all $m=1,2,3,\ldots$ we recover the exponential probability $\sum_{m}P_{m,t}(\delta t)=\kappa\exp(-\kappa\delta t)$ we had before, but now we have to distinguish between even $m$ (= odd $n$) and odd $m$ (= even $n$):

$$P_{\rm even}(\delta t)=\sum_{m=1,3,5}^{\infty}P_{m,t}(\delta t)=\cosh[\kappa(t-\delta t)]\kappa e^{-\kappa t}$$

$$P_{\rm odd}(\delta t)=\sum_{m=2,4,6}^{\infty}P_{m,t}(\delta t)=\sinh[\kappa(t-\delta t)]\kappa e^{-\kappa t}$$

and we're done:

$$p(x,t)=(1-e^{-\kappa t})^{-1}\int_0^t d\delta t\; [P_{\rm even}(\delta t)p_+(x,\delta t)
+P_{\rm odd}(\delta t)p_-(x,\delta t)]$$

$$\quad\quad=(1-e^{-\kappa t})^{-1}\int_0^t d\delta t\; \kappa e^{-\kappa t}\left[\cosh[\kappa(t-\delta t)]p_+(x,\delta t)
+\sinh[\kappa(t-\delta t)]p_-(x,\delta t)\right]$$

if we take $p_+=p_-\equiv p_0$ we recover the earlier result.

Comment: Thanks! This is along the lines of what I was hoping for, but I did not think of splitting it into even and odd switches. To be clear, does your general case still assume $\kappa_{+} = \kappa_{-}$? I think it does, otherwise would we still have a Poisson distribution for the number of switches?

(FYI, I want to play around with the math a bit before I accept the answer.)

Comment: Also, in your answer, shouldn't we also account for the fact that the integration interval is from $0$ to $t$. In your simple case, we will not normalize to $1$ if we integrate over $x$. There I think we have to divide by $1 - e^{-\kappa t}$. Likewise for $P_{\mathrm{even}}(t)$ and $P_{\mathrm{odd}}(t)$?

Comment: I've uncovered some other issues with this. In your simple case, you are integrating over the waiting time distribution $\psi(t') = \kappa_{0} e^{-\kappa_{0} t'}$. This means it is very probable to draw a time $t'$ near 0, and then decays it exponentially. Should we not integrate over $\psi(t - t')$, again with proper normalization? This means it is very probable to draw a time $t'$ near $t$, rather than near $0$.

Comment: Even in the case of one rate, it is not clear to me that $P_{\mathrm{even}}(t')$ and $P_{\mathrm{odd}}(t')$ can be derived by summing the Poission distribution - that gives a probability, which I don't think is the probability distribution of the time since the last switch. Thanks for your help though, it certainly is a step in the right direction.

Comment: @ionlet: I expanded the answer, hopefully answering all your queries; is it clear now?

Comment: This was beautiful, thank you! Accepted. I just used it as an intermediate step in a larger calculation, checked the answer against some stochastic simulations, and got a beautiful match. Thanks again!

Comment: One last question for you: In the case of two rates, the derivation will have to change because we can no longer use the Poisson distribution, right? (But perhaps it can be replaced by another appropriate distribution...)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be after $p(x,t)=P[S_t=+]p_+(x,t)+P[S_t=-]p_-(x,t)$ where $S_t$ is the state at time $t$. One knows that $S_0=+$ and that $S_t$ switches from $\pm$ to $\mp$ at rate $\kappa_\pm$.

Thus, $p(x,t)=q(t)p_+(x,t)+(1-q(t))p_-(x,t)$ where $q(t)=P[S_t=+]$ and the task is to compute $q(t)$. Note that $q(0)=1$ and that, when $s\to0$,
$$
q(t+s)=P[S_{t+s}=+]=q(t)(1-\kappa_+s+o(s))+(1-q(t))\kappa_-s+o(s),
$$
that is,
$$
q'(t)=-\kappa_+q(t)+\kappa_-(1-q(t)).
$$
This ODE yields $q(t)$ for every $t$, hence $p(x,t)$.

**Edit:** Second try, the model the OP is interested in might (or might not) be the following. Some quantities $p_+(x,t)$ and $p_-(x,t)$ are given for every $t\geqslant0$ and a state process $(S_t)$ is switching back and forth between states $+$ and $-$ at rates $\kappa_+$ and $\kappa_-$ and starting from $S_0=+$. Call $T_t$ the time of the last switch before $t$ (if no switch occurred before $t$, $T_t=0$). One is interested in 
$$
p(x,t)=E[p_{S_t}(x,t-T_t)]=
E[p_+(x,t-T_t);S_t=+]+E[p_-(x,t-T_t);S_t=-].
$$
From now on, let us choose $x$ and shorten $p(x,t)$, $p_+(x,t)$ and $p_-(x,t)$, $q(t)$ and $1-q(t)$ into $p(t)$, $p_+(t)$, $p_-(t)$, $q_+(t)$ and $q_-(t)$ respectively. When $r\to0$, during the time interval $(t,t+r)$ and assuming that $S_t=s$ with $s\in\{\pm\}$, either no switch happen and then $S_{t+r}=s$ and $t+r-T_{t+r}=t-T_t+r$, or a switch happen and then $S_{t+r}=-s$ and $t+r-T_{t+r}=o(1)$. Hence,
$$
p(t+r)=\sum_s\kappa_s rq_s(t)p_{-s}(0)+(1-\kappa_sr)E((p_s(t-T_t)+rp'_s(t-T_t));S_t=s)+o(r),
$$
which implies that
$$
p'(t)=\sum_s\kappa_s q_s(t)p_{-s}(0)+E(p'_s(t-T_t);S_t=s)-\kappa_sE(p_s(t-T_t);S_t=s).
$$
Conditionally on $S_t=s$, $t-T_t$ is distributed like $\min\{t,U_s\}$, where $U_s$ is exponential with parameter $\kappa_s$, hence, for every function $v$,
$$
E(v(t-T_t);S_t=s)=\mathrm e^{-\kappa_st}q_s(t)v(0)+q_s(t)\int_0^tv(u)\kappa_s\mathrm e^{-\kappa u}\mathrm du.
$$
Applying this to $v=p_s$ and to $v=p'_s$ shows that $t\mapsto p(t)$ solves an explicit integro-differential equation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I don't think it is as simple as that, though I'd be glad to be shown I'm wrong. Your $q(t)$ is perfectly fine, but there is an issue with your $p(x, t)$. It doesn't take into account the fact that $p_{\pm}(x, t)$ evolves with time as it waits in either state. In $p_{\pm}(x, t)$ is this time, not the global system time.

Comment: The answer is referring very precisely to the model you described. If you are interested in a different dynamics, please explain clearly what it is. Alternatively, describe what you think the problem with the derivation above is, avoiding vague terms such as "the fact that p±(x,t) evolves with time" (of course it "evolves with time", otherwise what would the argument $t$ be there for?).

Comment: $p_{\pm}(x, t)$ is the probability distribution for $x$ given that it enters state $\pm$ at $t = 0$. This is the key point, I mentioned it in the question. See also the comments above. What is a better way to describe this?

Comment: Could you confirm or infirm the Edit?

Comment: Something like this is what I'm looking for. The way you've written $t - T_{t}$ is what I meant originally. As written, is your $p(x, t)$ a probability distribution? It is not normalized, is it?

Comment: If $p_+(\ ,t)$ and $p_-(\ ,t)$ are probability distributions, so is $p(\ ,t)$ as a barycenter of these. (But the question is about fixing $x$ once and for all and working on $p(x,\ )$ from $p_-(x,\ )$ and $p_+(x,\ )$, actually.)

Comment: Your answer may be right, but I don't understand it that well. The above answer by Carlo Beenakker is what I was looking for and, I think, correct. Is yours the same as his? If yes, I'll accept yours too. (I can't see if it is or is not.)

Comment: I find a tad surprising that an answer restricted to the symmetric case $\kappa_+=\kappa_-$ is "what you were looking for" since the modifications needed to solve the general case are non trivial. For this reason, to ask whether my answer and the accepted one are the same seems rather moot and I do not feel much motivation to answer your last query. But since you seem happy with what you got, everything is perfect. (Unrelated: one cannot accept two answers.)